# MS SQL MULTIPLE CTE

Tags: sql-server

Вопрос заключается в:
Сперва выпалняется T1, потом T2 а затем результирующий?
Или T1 и T2 выполняются взаимосвязанно?

```
;WITH T1 AS
(
   ...
   WHERE ...
), T2 AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...) AS [rowNum]
              ,T1.* 
          FROM T
         WHERE T.partitionRowNum = 1
    )
    SELECT * FROM T2
    WHERE T2.rowNum > 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выполняются в том порядке, в каком написаны.

Поэтому во втором подзапросе (T2) можно использовать первый как таблицу:

```
with t1 as (
...
),
t2 as (
select * from t1
)
...
```